# Is it possible to use Symbol.species for plain objects?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/species) gives the following working example of `Symbol.species`:

> ```
> class MyArray extends Array {
>   // Overwrite species to the parent Array constructor
>   static get [Symbol.species]() { return Array; }
> }
> var a = new MyArray(1,2,3);
> var mapped = a.map(x => x * x);
>
> console.log(mapped instanceof MyArray); // false
> console.log(mapped instanceof Array);   // true
> ```

The [ECMAScript 2015 specifications](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#table-1) says:

> A function valued property that is the constructor function that is used to create derived objects.

The way I understand it it would be mainly used to Duck-Type in some way custom objects in order to trick the `instanceof` operator.
It seems very useful but I have not managed to use it on plain objects (FF 44.0a2):

```
let obj = {
  get [Symbol.species]() {
    return Array
  }
}

console.log(obj instanceof Array)  //false =(
console.log(obj instanceof Object) //true
```

Is there any way to use `Symbol.species` on plain objects in order to trick the `instanceof` operator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The way I understand it it would be mainly used to Duck-Type in some way custom objects in order to trick the `instanceof` operator.

Nope, that's what `Symbol.hasInstance` is good for (though it makes tricky constructors, e.g. for mixins, not tricky instances).

The point of `Symbol.species` is to let built-in methods determine the proper type for *derived objects*. Whenever a function is supposed to return a new instance of the same kind, it usually instantiates a `new this.constructor`, which might be a subclass of the class that defined the method. But you might not always want this when subclassing, and *that's* where `Symbol.species` comes in.
The example given by MDN is quite good, you just must not miss the distinction between `a` and `mapped`:

```
var a = new MyArray(1,2,3);
var mapped = a.map(x => x * x);

Object.getPrototypeOf(a) == MyArray.prototype; // true
Object.getPrototypeOf(mapped) == Array.prototype; // true
```

(As you know, `instanceof` <s>is</s> was just sugar for the reverse of `isPrototypeOf`)

So what happens here is that the [Array `map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is called on an instance of `MyArray`, and [creates a derived object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrayspeciescreate) that is now an instance of `Array` - because `a.constructor[Symbol.species]` said so. Without it, `map` would have created another `MyArray`.

This trick would work with plain objects just as well:

```
var b = {
    length: 0,
    map: Array.prototype.map,
    constructor: { // yes, usually a function
        [Symbol.species]: MyArray
    }
};
var mapped = b.map(x => x*x);
console.log(mapped instanceof MyArray); // true
```

I can't say whether it's any useful in this example, though :-)

Comment: I fail to see how `Symbol.species` act here. FF 44.0a2 may not yet support it, but in your example the log is `false` when I expected it not to be. Also, the MDN example and the spec seem to say it must be a function but you just defined a field. I have just tested the MDN example without the static Symbol, and the behaviour of logs don't change _at all_. I don't get how `map` would use the Symbol. Could you please show an example, a diff, where `Symbol.species` makes a real difference (assuming FF is not broken)? If I'm vampiring, pass me the stake and I'll handle myself.

Comment: Great explanation, still can't see how it is useful.

Comment: @Kyll: The `b[Symbol.species]` *is* a function - the `MyArray` constructor function. However, I missed that it's supposed to be a static property of the `.constructor`, please see my update.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. I get it now, it's much clearer, thanks a lot. The last log is however still `false` on FF 44.0a2. I suspect it comes from a broken implementation, since I haven't managed to make the MDN example work when changing the return value of `Symbol.species` to `MyArray`.

Comment: @TinyGiant hello there, have you got any real-life example for it?

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I admit that I'm not 100% sure, but I've gotten the impression that the answer is **no**.

I used two methods to determine this answer:

1. Finding an environment that clearly supports all of the features necessary to test this, and running the code in that environment directly
2. Referencing [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/)

The first point wasn't easy to test, and I wasn't entirely sure that I successfully did it. You used Firefox 44, but I decided to test another environment due to the fact that Kangax's support table says it [only supports the *existence* of Symbol.species](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Symbol), and none of the Array-like features. To see this, you can expand the Symbol.species section in the link above.

In this case, even Kangax is a bit confusing. I would expect there to be non-Array specific tests for Symbol.species aside from the existence test, but maybe I'm just not knowledge enough to understand that those tests cover all of the functionality of Symbols. I'm not sure!

While browsing the table, I saw that Edge supports all of the Symbol.species features. I loaded up my Windows VM, hopped on over to Edge 20, and pasted your code.

**In Edge 20, the code had the same result as your test in Firefox 44**.

So this began to give me confidence that the feature doesn't work in the way that you want it to. Just to make sure that Edge had its JavaScript in order, I decided to run the code from the MDN article you linked, and...I got a syntax error! It appears Edge is still updating its Class implementation due to late-in-the-game changes to the Class spec, so it's not enabled.

Their current implementation is, however, available through an experimental flag. So I flipped that on and was able to reproduce the result that MDN got.

And that was the extent of my JavaScript environment testing. I don't have 100% confidence in this test, but I would say that I'm *fairly* confidence in the result.

So onto the second method I used to determine my result: the specification.

I admit that I'm no expert at the ECMAScript specification. I do my best to understand it, but it is likely that I might misinterpret some of the information in there. The reason for this is because I'm not an ECMAScript master, so some of the technical jargon used is just way over my head.

Nevertheless, I can sometimes get the gist of what is being said. Here's a snippet that's about the Symbol @@species:

> Methods that create derived collection objects should call @@species to determine the constructor to use to create the derived objects. Subclass constructor may over-ride @@species to change the default constructor assignment.

The phrase "derived objects" is used quite frequently in describing this symbol, but it's not defined anywhere. One might interpret it to be a synonym of sorts with instantiated. If that's a correct interpretation, then this can likely only be used with constructors or classes.

Either way, it sounds as if @@species is an *active* Symbol, rather than a passive one. By this I mean that it sounds like it's a function that's actually called during the creation of an Object, which is then what determines the `instanceof` value, rather than a function that's called *at the time* of `instanceof` being called.

But anyway, take that interpretation with a grain of salt. Once again, I'm not 100% certain of any of this. I considered posting this as a comment rather than an answer, but it ended up getting quite long.

Comment: Indeed, it would have required 5 or 6 comments! The fact that the documentation on this is literally a freaking unclear two-liner doesn't make it any easier. I don't know if _anyone_ actually knows what it means haha. Very detailed answer, congratulations.